# IOS - ContainerView cuts off bottom of UIListView when viewed on non retina devices

Tags: ios

I have an app with a container view which has a UITableView embeded in it via an embed segue.

It looks and works perefectly on the 4" iphone but when I run it on the 3.5" simulator or phone it cuts of the bottom 40px or so of the list view.

[image: Screenshot of text being cut off]

I'm using autolayout. 
The container view is set to autoresize children ( which it does. If I make the container view smaller it still cuts of the bottom 40px )
I've got the top and bottom bars of the table view turned off.

Any help you could give would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to scroll to the portion which is not shown? If yes then it is working fine as the auto layout is resizing the container based on screen size but scroll view helps to show whole content.

Comment: I can force it to scroll but it bounces back to the position shown in the image.

Comment: In that case you need to check the auto layout constraints set. Ideally in this case only spacing to the table should be added and height should not be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. The table view has no contraints and I can't set any on it because it's a separate controller.